# Node.js argon2 Package Will Not Return String

Tags: node.js, npm, argon2-ffi

I am writing a web app that requires password hashing. I am using the `argon2` package from npm to achieve this.

Below is a function that I have written that is ment to return a string such as `$argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$QC3esXU28vknfnOGCjIIaA$f/2PjTMgmqP1nJhK9xT0bThniCEk28vX2eY6NdqrLP8` but insted the function returns `Promise { <pending> }` when the value is console.log(ed).

The code is:

```
async function hashPassword(password) {
    try {
        const hash = await argon2.hash(password);
        return hash;
    } catch {
        console.log('Error');
    }
}
const hashedPassword = hashPassword('password');
console.log(hashedPassword);
```

So, the output from the `console.log()` is `Promise { <pending> }`

Can someone please assist me in solving this problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **await** when call hashPassword():

```
async function hashPassword(password) {
    try {
        const hash = await argon2.hash(password);
        return hash;
    } catch {
        console.log('Error');
    }
}
const hashedPassword = await hashPassword('password');
console.log(hashedPassword);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because you are attempting to get the value of a `Promise` before it resolved. To fix that, just wait for the `Promise` to return a value. You can do that by changing your code to use the `then` function ([MDN Docs link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)).

```
async function hashPassword(password) {
    try {
        return await argon2.hash(password)
    } catch {
        console.log('Error');
    }
}

hashPassword('password').then((hashedPassword) => {
    console.log(hashedPassword);
});
```